# Using a psycopg2 converter to retrieve bytea data from PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to store Numpy arrays in a PostgreSQL database in binary (bytea) form. I can get this to work fine in test #1 (see below), but I don't want to have to be manipulating the data arrays before inserts and after selects every time - I want to use psycopg2's adapters and converters.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```py
import numpy as np
import psycopg2, psycopg2.extras


def my_adapter(spectrum):
    return psycopg2.Binary(spectrum)

def my_converter(my_buffer, cursor):
    return np.frombuffer(my_buffer)


class MyBinaryTest():

    # Connection info
    user = 'postgres'
    password = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
    host = 'localhost'
    database = 'test_binary'


    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def set_up(self):

        # Set up
        connection = psycopg2.connect(host=self.host, user=self.user, password=self.password)

        connection.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        try: # Clear out any old test database
            cursor.execute('drop database %s' % (self.database, ))
        except:
            pass

        cursor.execute('create database %s' % (self.database, ))
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()

        # Direct connectly to the database and set up our table            
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(host=self.host, user=self.user, password=self.password, database=self.database)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

        self.cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE spectrum (
            "sid" integer not null primary key,
            "data" bytea not null
            );

            CREATE SEQUENCE spectrum_id;
            ALTER TABLE spectrum
                ALTER COLUMN sid
                    SET DEFAULT NEXTVAL('spectrum_id');
            ''')
        self.connection.commit()



    def perform_test_one(self):

        # Lets do a test

        shape = (2, 100)
        data = np.random.random(shape)

        # Binary up the data
        send_data = psycopg2.Binary(data)

        self.cursor.execute('insert into spectrum (data) values (%s) returning sid;', [send_data])
        self.connection.commit()

        # Retrieve the data we just inserted
        query = self.cursor.execute('select * from spectrum')
        result = self.cursor.fetchall()

        print "Type of data retrieved:", type(result[0]['data'])

        # Convert it back to a numpy array of the same shape
        retrieved_data = np.frombuffer(result[0]['data']).reshape(*shape)

        # Ensure there was no problem
        assert np.all(retrieved_data == data)
        print "Everything went swimmingly in test one!"

        return True

    def perform_test_two(self):

        if not self.use_adapters: return False

        # Lets do a test

        shape = (2, 100)
        data = np.random.random(shape)

        # No changes made to the data, as the adapter should take care of it (and it does)

        self.cursor.execute('insert into spectrum (data) values (%s) returning sid;', [data])
        self.connection.commit()

        # Retrieve the data we just inserted
        query = self.cursor.execute('select * from spectrum')
        result = self.cursor.fetchall()

        # No need to change the type of data, as the converter should take care of it
        # (But, we never make it here)

        retrieved_data = result[0]['data']

        # Ensure there was no problem
        assert np.all(retrieved_data == data.flatten())
        print "Everything went swimmingly in test two!"

        return True


    def setup_adapters_and_converters(self):

        # Set up test adapters
        psycopg2.extensions.register_adapter(np.ndarray, my_adapter)

        # Register our converter
        self.cursor.execute("select null::bytea;")
        my_oid = self.cursor.description[0][1]

        obj = psycopg2.extensions.new_type((my_oid, ), "numpy_array", my_converter)
        psycopg2.extensions.register_type(obj, self.connection)

        self.connection.commit()

        self.use_adapters = True


    def tear_down(self):

        # Tear down

        self.cursor.close()
        self.connection.close()

        connection = psycopg2.connect(host=self.host, user=self.user, password=self.password)

        connection.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('drop database %s' % (self.database, ))
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()


test = MyBinaryTest()
test.set_up()
test.perform_test_one()
test.setup_adapters_and_converters()
test.perform_test_two()
test.tear_down()
```

Now, test #1 works fine. When I take the code I have used in test 1 and setup a psycopg2 adapter and converter, it does not work (test 2). This is because the data being fed to the converter is not actually a buffer anymore; it's PosgreSQL's string representation of bytea. The output is as follows:

```
In [1]: run -i test_binary.py
Type of data retrieved: type 'buffer'>
Everything went swimmingly in test one!
ERROR: An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (273, 0))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/Users/andycasey/thesis/scope/scope/test_binary.py in <module>()
    155 test.perform_test_one()
    156 test.setup_adapters_and_converters()
--> 157 test.perform_test_two()
    158 test.tear_down()
    159 

/Users/andycasey/thesis/scope/scope/test_binary.py in perform_test_two(self)
    101         # Retrieve the data we just inserted

    102         query = self.cursor.execute('select * from spectrum')
--> 103         result = self.cursor.fetchall()
    104 
    105         # No need to change the type of data, as the converter should take care of it


/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.pyc in fetchall(self)
     81     def fetchall(self):
     82         if self._prefetch:
---> 83             res = _cursor.fetchall(self)
     84         if self._query_executed:
     85             self._build_index()

/Users/andycasey/thesis/scope/scope/test_binary.py in my_converter(my_buffer, cursor)
      7 
      8 def my_converter(my_buffer, cursor):
----> 9     return np.frombuffer(my_buffer)
     10 
     11 

ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size
WARNING: Failure executing file: <test_binary.py>

In [2]: %debug
> /Users/andycasey/thesis/scope/scope/test_binary.py(9)my_converter()
      8 def my_converter(my_buffer, cursor):
----> 9     return np.frombuffer(my_buffer)
     10 

ipdb> my_buffer
'\\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'
```

Does anyone know how I can either (a) de-serialize the string representation coming back to me in my_converter so I return a Numpy array each time, or (b) force PostgreSQL/psycopg2 to send the buffer representation to the converter (which I can use) instead of the string representation?

Thanks!

I'm on OS X 10.6.8 with Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515), PostgreSQL 9.0.3 and psycopg2 2.4 (dt dec pq3 ext)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The format you see in the debugger is easy to parse: it is PostgreSQL hex binary format (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-binary.html). psycopg can parse that format and return a buffer containing the data; you can use that buffer to obtain an array. Instead of writing a typecaster from scratch, write one invoking the original func and postprocess its result. Sorry but I can't remember its name now and I'm writing from a mobile: you may get further help from the mailing list.

---

Edit: complete solution.

The default bytea
typecaster (which is the object that can parse the postgres binary
representation and return a buffer object out of it) is
psycopg2.BINARY. We can use it to create a typecaster converting to
array instead:

```
In [1]: import psycopg2

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: a = np.eye(3)

In [4]: a
Out[4]:
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
      [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
      [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])

In [5]: cnn = psycopg2.connect('')


# The adapter: converts from python to postgres
# note: this only works on numpy version whose arrays 
# support the buffer protocol,
# e.g. it works on 1.5.1 but not on 1.0.4 on my tests.

In [12]: def adapt_array(a):
  ....:     return psycopg2.Binary(a)
  ....:

In [13]: psycopg2.extensions.register_adapter(np.ndarray, adapt_array)


# The typecaster: from postgres to python

In [21]: def typecast_array(data, cur):
  ....:     if data is None: return None
  ....:     buf = psycopg2.BINARY(data, cur)
  ....:     return np.frombuffer(buf)
  ....:

In [24]: ARRAY = psycopg2.extensions.new_type(psycopg2.BINARY.values,
'ARRAY', typecast_array)

In [25]: psycopg2.extensions.register_type(ARRAY)


# Now it works "as expected"

In [26]: cur = cnn.cursor()

In [27]: cur.execute("select %s", (a,))

In [28]: cur.fetchone()[0]
Out[28]: array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.])
```

As you know, np.frombuffer(a) loses the array shape, so you will have
to figure out a way to preserve it.

Comment: Thanks @piro - I have tried parsing this hex format (and the PostgreSQL escape format) using things like `np.frombuffer(buffer(my_buffer[2:].decode('hex'), 0, 1600))`, but I've been unsuccessful in retrieving the original array. If you can recall the functions to parse this format I'd be very grateful. I've asked on the mailing list and they are equally keen to see how this problem is resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

pFor the case of numpy arrays one can avoid the buffer strategy with all its disadvantages like the loss of shape and data type. Following a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621513/python-insert-numpy-array-into-sqlite3-database) about storing a numpy array in sqlite3 one can easily adapt the approach for postgres.

```
import os
import psycopg2 as psql
import numpy as np

# converts from python to postgres
def _adapt_array(text):
    out = io.BytesIO()
    np.save(out, text)
    out.seek(0)
    return psql.Binary(out.read())

# converts from postgres to python
def _typecast_array(value, cur):
    if value is None:
        return None

    data = psql.BINARY(value, cur)
    bdata = io.BytesIO(data)
    bdata.seek(0)
    return np.load(bdata)

con = psql.connect('')

psql.extensions.register_adapter(np.ndarray, _adapt_array)
t_array = psql.extensions.new_type(psql.BINARY.values, "numpy", _typecast_array)
psql.extensions.register_type(t_array)

cur = con.cursor()
```

Now one can create and fill a table (with `a` defined as in the previous post)

```
cur.execute("create table test (column BYTEA)")
cur.execute("insert into test values(%s)", (a,))
```

And restore the numpy object

```
cur.execute("select * from test")
cur.fetchone()[0]
```

Result:

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried both of these answers and couldn't get them to work until I modified Daniel's code to use `np.savetxt` and `np.loadtxt` and changed his typecaster

```
bdata = BytesIO(data[1:-1])
```

so the two functions now look like

```
def _adapt_array(arr):
    out = BytesIO()
    np.savetxt(out, arr, fmt='%.2f')
    out.seek(0)
    return pg2.Binary(out.read())

def _typecast_array(value, cur):
    if value is None:
       return None
    data = pg2.BINARY(value, cur)
    bdata = BytesIO(data[1:-1])
    bdata.seek(0)
    return np.loadtxt(bdata)

pg2.extensions.register_adapter(np.ndarray, _adapt_array)
t_array = pg2.extensions.new_type(pg2.BINARY.values, 'numpy', _typecast_array)
pg2.extensions.register_type(t_array)
```

The error I was getting was `could not convert string to float: '[473.07'`. I suspect this fix will only work for flat arrays but that's how my data was structured so it worked for me.