# Sqlite database organization

Tags: sqlite, sql-delete, composite-key

So I have a collection of recorded rat vocalizations (that's right the animal). There are several rats I have recordings from. In addition, each recording is sampled at 300e3 Hz and is several ms in duration. So each recording consists of tens of thousands of floats stored in a column called values. I've stored all this in an sqlite db, but I have a question about the optimal way to organize it. Right now I have a composite primary key (rat_id char(2), recording_# INT, time_step INT). The recording_# starts at 0 for each new rat_id, and the time_step starts at 0 for each new recording_#. The problem comes in when I try to delete a recording and deincrement all values for recording_index greater than the one I deleted. This of course takes forever because it has to do millions of operations each time this happens.

```
cur.execute("DELETE FROM recordings WHERE ratid=? AND recording_index=?", (self.rat, recording_index))
cur.execute("UPDATE recordings SET recording_index = -(recording_index-1) WHERE ratid=? AND recording_index>?", (self.rat, recording_index))
cur.execute("UPDATE recordings SET recording_index = -recording_index WHERE ratid=? AND recording_index<0", (self.rat,))
```

So is there a better way to organize the table such that the deincrement operation doesn't take as long, or should I just not bother with the deincrement operation. I don't really need to do it. I'm just being kind of overly concerned with details.

Comment: Don't store index positions. Store sequence numbers. Use ordering. Embrace the gaps.

Comment: What do you mean by sequence numbers?

Comment: A value that supplies an ordering within a sequence, without referring to a dense index - needs not be sequential.

Comment: Sorry, maybe you can point me to some docs, because I'm not catching your meaning.

Comment: Don't update the recording_index. Databases aren't arrays. Then recording_index is no longer sequential over [0..n), which is most likely fine.

Comment: Do you ever need to access individual float values? Why don't you store the recordings as blobs?

Comment: I don't need to access individual floats. So I'm doing this through python. Can I store a numpy array as a blob?

Comment: Apparently you can't store np arrays, but i figured out how to register your own datatypes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621513/python-insert-numpy-array-into-sqlite3-database