# inserting numpy integer types into sqlite with python3

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x, numpy, python-db-api

What is the correct way to insert the values of numpy integer objects into databases in python 3?  In python 2.7 numpy numeric datatypes insert cleanly into sqlite, but they don't in python 3

```
import numpy as np
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
conn.execute("CREATE TABLE foo (id INTEGER NOT NULL, primary key (id))")
conn.execute("insert into foo values(?)", (np.int64(100),)) # <-- Fails in 3
```

The np.float types seem to still work just fine in both 2 and 3.

```
    conn.execute("insert into foo values(?)", (np.float64(101),))
```

In python 2, the numpy scalar integer datatypes are no longer instances of int, even converting integer-valued floating point numbers to ints.

```
   isinstance(np.int64(1), int)  # <- true for 2, false for python 3
```

Is this why the dbapi no longer works seamlessly with numpy?

Comment: A  numpy integer type isn't just the byte representation of the number (it's `.item()` value); is an object, almost the same as a single element, 0d, array.  So I don't think you can save it, in all of its numpy glory, in a database.  You could save its integer value, or a some byte equivalent, but not the full numpy object.  Is there anything in `sqlite3` about saving a user defined object instance?

Comment: There is always the scary pickle-approach (targeting TEXT type), or something more modern and binary-based like [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) (targeting BLOB type).

Comment: What's the advantage to saving `np.int64(100)` instead of `100`?  Is there some useful information that you couldn't recover during a fetch?  You might look at how modules like SQLAlchemy handle the sql-object interface.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621513/python-insert-numpy-array-into-sqlite3-database is an example of previous SO questions.  The solution there to saving a whole array is to write `np.save` to a byteString and saving that as a custom type in the database.  Search `sqlite3` and `numpy`.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm creating the np.int64 explicitly as an example.  I'm not trying to save the int64 objects into the database, just their integer representation.

Comment: OK, I glossed over the py2 v py3 difference.  If you'd tried to save an element of an array I might have gone off on another rabbit track. `item()` will strip off the `numpy` object wrapper. I don't have `numpy` installed on py2 to test that side of the problem.

Comment: Py3 removed the distinction between integer and long. So some numpy integer dtypes no longer subclass `integer`.  Floats still subclass.  Can you still save an element of a float array?

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, apparently you can insert np.floatXXX types.

Comment: In testing a structured array to sqlite3 write for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798033/fast-query-in-formatted-data/38808983, I found that `tolist()` handles this `integer` issue nicely: `c.executemany(exec_string, data.tolist())`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to sqlite3 docs:

> To use other Python types with SQLite, you must adapt them to one of the sqlite3 module’s supported types for SQLite: one of NoneType, int, float, str, bytes.

So you can **adapt** *np.int64* type. You should do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import sqlite3

sqlite3.register_adapter(np.int64, lambda val: int(val))
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
conn.execute("CREATE TABLE foo (id INTEGER NOT NULL, primary key (id))")
conn.execute("insert into foo values(?)", (np.int64(100),))
```

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html#registering-an-adapter-callable)

Answer (score 6):

Rather than:

```
sqlite3.register_adapter(np.int64, lambda val: int(val))
```

You can use:

```
sqlite3.register_adapter(np.int64, int)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the .item() method.

```
np.int64(100).item()
```

The advantage of this solution is that is portable and not sqlite3 specific.

For reference about numpy type conversions with the .item() method, refer to https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html#numpy.ndarray.item