# Fast query in formatted data

Tags: python, database, numpy, indexing, mapping

In my program I need to query through metadata.

I read data into `numpy` record array `A` from csv-like text file ** without duplicate rows**.

```
var1|var2|var3|var4|var5|var6
'a1'|'b1'|'c1'|1.2|2.2|3.4
'a1'|'b1'|'c4'|3.2|6.2|3.2
'a2'|''|'c1'|1.4|5.7|3.8
'a2'|'b1'|'c2'|1.2|2.2|3.4
'a3'|''|'c2'|1.2|2.2|3.4
'a1'|'b2'|'c4'|7.2|6.2|3.2
...
```

There are **millions** of rows and the query in nested loops can be up to **billion** times (mostly matching the first 3 columns), so the efficiency becomes critical.

There are 3 types of queries and the first one is the most frequent.

- Get rows matching one or more of the first 3 columns with given strings, e.g.,

  - To match a record where `var1='a2'` and `var2='b1'`,

    ```
     ind = np.logical_and(A['var1']=='a2', A['var2']=='b1')
    ```
  - To match a record where `var1='a2'`, `var2='b1'` and `var3='c1'`,

    ```
     ind = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(A['var1']=='a2', A['var2']=='b1'), A['var3']=='c1')
    ```

As one can see, each time we compare the all elements of columns with given strings.

I thought mapping could be a more efficient way for indexing, so I converted the recarray `A` to a dict `D = {'var1_var2_var3`: [var4, var5, var6], ...}`, and search through the keys by`fnmatch(keys, pat)`. I'm not sure it's a better way.

Or I can make a hierachical dict `{'var1':{'var2':{'var3':[],...},...},...}` or in-memory hdf5 `/var1/var2/var3` and just try to get the item if exists. This looks the fastest way?

The latter two types of queries are not very frequent and I can accept the way of numpy recarray comparison.

- Get all rows the numeric values in the latter columns in a specific range, e.g.,

  - get rows where '1

    ```
    ind = np.logical_and(1<A['var4']<3), 0<A['var5']<3)
    ```
- A combination of the above two, e.g.,

  - get rows where `var2='b1'`, '1

    ```
    ind = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(A['var2']=='b1', 1<A['var4']<3), 0<A['var5']<3)
    ```

`SQL` could be a good way but it looks too heavy to use database for this small task. And I don't have authority to install database support everywhere.

Any suggestions for data structure for fast in-memory query? (If it is hard to have a simple customed implementation, `sqlite` and `pandas.dateframe` seem to be possible solutions, as suggested.)

Comment: Have you looked at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html ?

Comment: Explain your `numpy` efficiency worries more?  As for a database solution, `sqlite3` can be used in-memory.

Comment: @hpaulj  every query requires comparing all the millions of items with given values, which looks a big waste. I ever tried to use `dict` but it seems the regexp matching is not faster. If it is hard to have a simple customed python code for the purpose, `sqlite` and `pandas.dateframe` seem to be possible solutions.

Comment: In `numpy` the bilateral tests have to be written as `(1<A['var4'])&(A['var4']<3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your file sample ('b' for py3)

```
In [51]: txt=b"""var1|var2|var3|var4|var5|var6
    ...: 'a1'|'b1'|'c1'|1.2|2.2|3.4
    ...: 'a1'|'b1'|'c4'|3.2|6.2|3.2
    ...: 'a2'|''|'c1'|1.4|5.7|3.8
    ...: 'a2'|'b1'|'c2'|1.2|2.2|3.4
    ...: 'a3'|''|'c2'|1.2|2.2|3.4
    ...: 'a1'|'b2'|'c4'|7.2|6.2|3.2"""
```

A simple read leaves me with the double layer of quoting

```
data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), names=True, delimiter='|', dtype=None)

array([(b"'a1'", b"'b1'", b"'c1'", 1.2, 2.2, 3.4), ...
    dtype=[('var1', 'S4'), ('var2', 'S4'), ('var3', 'S4'), ('var4', '<f8'), ('var5', '<f8'), ('var6', '<f8')])
```

So I'll define a converter to strip those (a `csv` reader might do it as well):

```
def foo(astr):
    return eval(astr)

In [55]: A = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), names=True, delimiter='|', dtype='U3,U3,U3,f8,f8,f8', converters={0:foo,1:foo,2:foo})
In [56]: A
Out[56]: 
array([('a1', 'b1', 'c1', 1.2, 2.2, 3.4),
       ('a1', 'b1', 'c4', 3.2, 6.2, 3.2), 
       ('a2', '', 'c1', 1.4, 5.7, 3.8),
       ('a2', 'b1', 'c2', 1.2, 2.2, 3.4), 
       ('a3', '', 'c2', 1.2, 2.2, 3.4),
       ('a1', 'b2', 'c4', 7.2, 6.2, 3.2)], 
      dtype=[('var1', '<U3'), ('var2', '<U3'), ('var3', '<U3'), ('var4', '<f8'), ('var5', '<f8'), ('var6', '<f8')])
```

and I can write tests like

```
In [57]: (A['var1']=='a2')&(A['var2']=='b1')
Out[57]: array([False, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
In [58]: (1<A['var4'])&(A['var4']<3)
Out[58]: array([ True, False,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

The tests over all records of `A` are being done in compile `numpy` code, so they shouldn't be that slow.

This data could also be viewed as 2 multicolumn fields

```
In [59]: dt = np.dtype([('labels', '<U3', (3,)), ('data', '<f8', (3,))])
In [60]: A1 = A.view(dt)
In [61]: A1
Out[61]: 
array([(['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], [1.2, 2.2, 3.4]),
       (['a1', 'b1', 'c4'], [3.2, 6.2, 3.2]),
       (['a2', '', 'c1'], [1.4, 5.7, 3.8]),
       (['a2', 'b1', 'c2'], [1.2, 2.2, 3.4]),
       (['a3', '', 'c2'], [1.2, 2.2, 3.4]),
       (['a1', 'b2', 'c4'], [7.2, 6.2, 3.2])], 
      dtype=[('labels', '<U3', (3,)), ('data', '<f8', (3,))])
```

Or loaded directly with

```
A = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), skip_header=1, delimiter='|', dtype='(3)U3,(3)f8', converters={0:foo,1:foo,2:foo})
```

Then tests could be written as:

```
In [64]: (A1['labels'][:,0]=='a1') & (A1['labels'][:,1]=='b2') & ((A1['data']<6).any(axis=1))
Out[64]: array([False, False, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [65]: (A1['labels'][:,[0,1]]==['a1','b2']).all(axis=1)
Out[65]: array([False, False, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Sometimes it might be clearer to give individual columns their own id:

```
var1 = A1['labels'][:,0]   # or A['var1']
....
(var1=='a1')&(var2='b1')&...
```

Repeated queries, or combinations could be saved.

I believe `pandas` stores its series in `numpy` arrays, with different dtype for each column (and object dtype if types varies within a column).  But I haven't seen discussion of `pandas` speed and speed tricks.  I don't expect much speed improvement unless it provides for some sort of indexing.

I can imagine writing this data to a database.  `sqlite3` is builtin and has a `memory` mode so you don't need file access.  But I'm sufficiently out of practice with that code that I'll pass on demonstrating it.  Nor do I have a sense of how easy or fast it is to do these sorts of queries.

https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2007-August/013350.html has some code that can save a structured array to a sqlite3 database.  It includes a function that converts a `dtype` into a table creation statement.

====================

I've got that `pipermail` example working with `python3`. The test example has 11 fields.  With 5000 records,

```
data[np.where(data['id']=='id2000')]
```

is 6x faster than a corresponding `sqlite3` query (with an existing `cursor`):

```
cursor.execute('select * from data where id=?',('id2000',))
cursor.fetchone()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), it is built for tasks like this:

```
# Import
import pandas as pd

# Read CSV
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv')

# Selection criteria
# using `.query` method:
df.query('var1 == "a2" & var3 == "c1"')
df.query('var2 == "b1" & 1 < var4 < 3 & 0 < var5 < 3')
# using indexing:
df[(df['var1'] == 'a2') & (df['var3'] == 'c1')]
df[(df['var2'] == 'b1') & df['var4'].between(1,3) & df['var5'].between(0,3)]
# using `.where` method:
df.where((df['var1'] == 'a2') & (df['var3'] == 'c1'))
df.where(df['var2'] == 'b1') & df['var4'].between(1,3) & df['var5'].between(0,3))
```

[More indexing and selecting information](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/indexing.html)

Comment: I guess the query in `pandas.dataframe` is the same as the `numpy.recarray` comparison in the background? or it is optimized using some tricks?

Comment: `pandas` tends to use `numpy` arrays for columns, though the dtype might not be structured (recarray).  It does have faster code for tasks like loading a CSV, but I doubt if there's much of a speed difference in tasks like this.  But you just might have to do your own speed tests.

Comment: @Lee, Pandas parses queries using `numexpr`, which is allegedly quite efficient at these things. Like @hpaulj says, you will have to do your own tests. The great thing though is that you can create masks out of your conditions. So if you have a fixed combination that you want to index, you can simply create a mask, and reuse that in your program. Ex: `mask = (df['var1'] == 'a2') & (df['var3'] == 'c1')` is a mask that you can use to index into your data frame like so: `df[mask]`. Potentially, you make comparisons once, and reuse the results.

Comment: Further, @Lee, you may not even need masking and indexing in pandas. There is the `groupby` method, for instance with can group your data on different criterea, and apply any number of functions to the members of each group.