# Python 3 SQLite IntegrityError

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x

I'm trying to debug why my code is returning an error. I have a SQLite database and I'm trying to add records to a specific table. My code has worked perfectly fine in Python 2.7, but I get `IntegrityError` in Python 3.5

```
new_rec = [1, 12.0, -12.0, None, None, b'fakesource', None, None]
self.conn.execute("INSERT INTO {} VALUES({})".format('sources', ','.join('?' * len(columns))), tuple(new_rec))
```

`columns` is a list of the column names in my table. It has the same length as `new_rec`.

This returns:

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch
```

For reference, here is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE sources (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
ra REAL, 
dec REAL, 
designation TEXT, 
publication_id INTEGER, 
shortname TEXT, 
names TEXT, 
comments TEXT)
```

Changing `new_rec` to something like: `new_rec = [1, 12.0, None, None, None, None, None, None]` still causes an `IntegrityError`. Any thoughts?

#### Update 8/16/2016

I've examined the types of `new_rec` and believe I found the problem:

```
[<class 'numpy.int64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'NoneType'>, <class 'NoneType'>, <class 'numpy.bytes_'>, <class 'NoneType'>, <class 'NoneType'>]
```

Looks like sqlite3 does not play nice with numpy.int64: [inserting numpy integer types into sqlite with python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753737/inserting-numpy-integer-types-into-sqlite-with-python3)

Comment: An integrity error means that an entry with the same primary key already exists in the table. Are you trying to insert a row with a key of 1 when the table already has one? It may not be a Python issue...it could just be that you originally inserted the row in Python 2.7.

Comment: No the table is empty and changing the id to be something else still causes the error. It feels to me like something else in my code, or maybe my version of sqlite3, is breaking as there shouldn't be a datatype mistmatch error.