# Storing numpy array in sqlite3 database with python issue

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sqlite

I have a problem with storing a numpy array in sqlite database. I have 1 table with Name and Data.

```
import sqlite3 as sql
from DIP import dip      # function to caclculate numpy array
name = input('Enter your full name\t')
data = dip()
con = sql.connect('Database.db')
c = con.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database(Name text, Vein real )")
con.commit()
c.execute("INSERT INTO database VALUES(?,?)", (name, data))
con.commit()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM database")
df = c.fetchall()
print(data)
print(df)
con.close()
```

Everything is fine but when Data is being stored instead of this:

```
[('Name', 0.03908678  0.04326234  0.18298542 ...,  0.15228545  0.09972548   0.03992807)]
```

I have this:

```
[('Name', b'\xccX+\xa8.\x03\xa4?\xf7\xda[\x1f ..., x10l\xc7?\xbf\x14\x12\)]
```

What is problem with this? Thank you.

P.S. I tried the solution from here [Python insert numpy array into sqlite3 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621513/python-insert-numpy-array-into-sqlite3-database) but it didn't work. And my numpy array is being calculated from skimage (scikit-image) library with HOG (histogram of oriented gradients). Maybe that's a problem...
Also tried to calculate and store it from opencv3 but have the same issue.

Comment: You need to show how the solution(s) in the link did not work.  What exactly did you try?  What was the problem?

Comment: I tried the answer of unutbu to create and convert my own datatype and then to insert and read the data from database. The result was the same as i described in my question above. It stores the numpy ndarray to the database but when you read it is somehow encoded.

Comment: I wonder if it is saving a byte representation of the array's data buffer.  Compare this value to `data.tostring()`.

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that it is saving `data.tostring()` to the database, I tried decoding it with `fromstring`.

Using your displayed string, and trimming off a few bytes I got:

```
In [79]: np.fromstring(b'\xccX+\xa8.\x03\xa4?\xf7\xda[\x1f\x10l\xc7?', float)
Out[79]: array([ 0.03908678,  0.18298532])
```

There's at least one matching number, so this looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and I have found out that sqlite has problem of storing custom numpy float type (`np.float32` in my case).

Change the type of float values to string and it will work fine.

`[float(x) for x in data]`