# syntax to UPDATE a BLOB field in an existing SQLite record?

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update, blob

What is the syntax to `UPDATE` a `BLOB` field in an existing `SQLite` record, using Python? I create a 13x13 array of floats and want to Update a specific record (i.e. using a `WHERE` clause) in my table with that array.

What is the proper `UPDATE` syntax?

The array has the following form:

```
[ 4.65640926e+00  5.59250259e+00  5.28963852e+00  1.60680866e+00
  -3.39492680e-01 -4.76834650e-01 -4.76834650e-01 -2.29132240e-01
   1.49733067e+00  1.51563072e+00  1.49733067e+00  9.53471420e-01
  -1.40306473e+00]

 [ 5.28963852e+00  5.34537315e+00  5.05013466e+00  1.48362923e+00
  -3.69843300e-01 -4.76834650e-01 -4.76834650e-01 -2.29132240e-01
   7.60705290e-01  1.49733067e+00  9.53471420e-01  3.05504260e-01
  -1.40306473e+00]
```

Totaling 13 rows of 13 sub-arrays.

Thank you,
Bill

Comment: You update in exactly the same way as you do the inserting. Show that code.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax for the SQL is :-

```
UPDATE mytable SET myblobcolumn = x'ffeedd' WHERE your_where_clause;
```

Where

- **mytable** is the table name,
- **myblobcolumn** is the name of the column that is to be updated,
- **your_where_clause** is the selection criteria,
- **x'ffeedd'** is the byte array value, converted to hexadecimal, that is to be used to update the column.

*Obviously the above are only representations, you would have to substitute appropriate values*

[image]

- [SQL As Understood By SQLite - UPDATE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html)
- [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Answer (score 0):

A friend pointed me to this solution, which works nicely. The original answer was from StackOverflow, to give proper credit.

def adapt_array(arr):
    """
    Reformat a numpy array so as to be writeable to  SQLite BLOB fields
    Input: Numpy Array
    Returns: formatted Binary BLOB compatable 
    Code Source: [Python insert numpy array into sqlite3 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621513/python-insert-numpy-array-into-sqlite3-database/31312102#31312102)
    """
    out = io.BytesIO()
    np.save(out, arr)
    out.seek(0)
    return sqlite3.Binary(out.read())

def convert_array(text):
    """
    Reformat a SQLite BLOB field into the originating Numpy array
    Input: Numpy BLOB from SQLite
    Returns: numpy array 
    Code Source: [Python insert numpy array into sqlite3 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621513/python-insert-numpy-array-into-sqlite3-database/31312102#31312102)
    """
    out = io.BytesIO(text)
    out.seek(0)
    return np.load(out)