# Update blob data in existing database

Tags: python, sqlite, blob

I want to update a field blob in a existing database but it raises me an error.

```
execute("UPDATE table_name SET blob_column={} WHERE var1=1 AND var2=2".format(b"\x01\x02")))
```

I want to replace the actual data on the blob_column with \x01\x02 instead. This error occurs :

```
error : near "'\x01\x02'": syntax error (UPDATE table_name SET blob_column=b'\x01\x02' WHERE var1=1 AND var2=2)
```

Found this topic but don't understand : [syntax to UPDATE a BLOB field in an existing SQLite record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217595/syntax-to-update-a-blob-field-in-an-existing-sqlite-record)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for the blob value should be `x'0102'` not `b'\x01\x02'` as per

```
UPDATE table_name SET blob_column= x'0102' WHERE var1=1 AND var2=2
```

The value being hexadecimal e.g. `x'aaff'`.

Each pair of characters is a byte so `x'0102'` is a blob that is two bytes in length.