# Convert byte array back to numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

You can convert a numpy array to bytes using `.tobytes()` function.

How do decode it back from this bytes array to numpy array?
I tried like this for array i of shape (28,28)

`>>k=i.tobytes()`

`>>np.frombuffer(k)==i`

`False`

also tried with uint8 as well.

Comment: Have you tried looking at this? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html

Comment: It doesn't work that way.

I tried like this for i of shape (28,28)

first i tried 

`>>k=i.tobytes()
>>np.frombuffer(k)==i
False
also tried with uint8 as well not working

`

Comment: Are you working with MNIST? :)

Comment: yes, it was on top of MNIST. It was used as an example dataset.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A couple of issues with what you're doing:

1. `frombuffer` will always interpret the input as a 1-dimensional array. It's the first line of the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html). So you'd have to reshape to be `(28, 28)`.
2. The default `dtype` is `float`. So if you didn't serialize out floats, then you'll have to specify the `dtype` manually (a priori no one can tell what a stream of bytes means: you have to say what they represent).
3. If you want to make sure the arrays are equal, you have to use `np.array_equal`. Using `==` will do an elementwise operation, and return a `numpy` array of bools (this presumably isn't what you want).

> How do decode it back from this bytes array to numpy array?

Example:

```
In [3]: i = np.arange(28*28).reshape(28, 28)

In [4]: k = i.tobytes()

In [5]: y = np.frombuffer(k, dtype=i.dtype)

In [6]: y.shape
Out[6]: (784,)

In [7]: np.array_equal(y.reshape(28, 28), i)
Out[7]: True
```

HTH.

Comment: Important: the object returned from `np.frombuffer()` is read-only

Answer (score 20):

While you could use `tobytes()`, it isn't the ideal method as it doesn't store shape information of the numpy array.

In cases where you have to send it to another process where you have no information about the shape, you will have to send the shape information explicitly.

A more elegant solution would be saving it to a BytesIO buffer using `np.save` and recovering using `np.load`. In this, you don't need to specifically store shape information anywhere and can easily recover your numpy array from the byte value.

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from io import BytesIO

>>> x = np.arange(28*28).reshape(28, 28)
>>> x.shape
(28, 28)

# save in to BytesIo buffer 
>>> np_bytes = BytesIO()
>>> np.save(np_bytes, x, allow_pickle=True)

# get bytes value
>>> np_bytes = np_bytes.getvalue()
>>> type(np_bytes)
<class 'bytes'>

# load from bytes into numpy array
>>> load_bytes = BytesIO(np_bytes)
>>> loaded_np = np.load(load_bytes, allow_pickle=True)

# shape is preserved
>>> loaded_np.shape
(28, 28)

# both arrays are equal without sending shape
>>> np.array_equal(x,loaded_np)
True
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach is very very slow for large numpy arrays. See related SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62352670/deserialization-of-large-numpy-arrays-using-pickle-is-order-of-magnitude-slower?noredirect=1#comment110277408_62352670

Answer (score 8):

For your convenience, here is a serialization/deserialization function implementing [Saket Kumar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61838233/2496293) answer.

```py
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np

def array_to_bytes(x: np.ndarray) -> bytes:
    np_bytes = BytesIO()
    np.save(np_bytes, x, allow_pickle=True)
    return np_bytes.getvalue()


def bytes_to_array(b: bytes) -> np.ndarray:
    np_bytes = BytesIO(b)
    return np.load(np_bytes, allow_pickle=True)

# ----------
# quick test

def test():
    x = np.random.uniform(0, 155, (2, 3)).astype(np.float16)
    b = array_to_bytes(x)
    x1 = bytes_to_array(b)
    assert np.all(x == x1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the binarized array, not restricted to the `np.tobytes` method, you can use `pickle.dumps` and `pickle.loads`

Here goes an example

```py
import pickle
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, [2,2])
A_bytes=pickle.dumps(A, protocol=0)
A_restore=pickle.loads(A_bytes)

# test byte type and restored np mat
np.testing.assert_array_equal(A_restore, A)
assert type(A_bytes)==bytes
```