# Deserialization of large numpy arrays using pickle is order of magnitude slower than using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, deserialization, python-3.8

I am deserializing large numpy arrays (500MB in this example) and I find the results vary by orders of magnitude between approaches. Below are the 3 approaches I've timed.

I'm receiving the data from the `multiprocessing.shared_memory` package, so the data comes to me as a `memoryview` object. But in these simple examples, I just pre-create a byte array to run the test.

> I wonder if there are any mistakes in these approaches, or if there are other techniques I didn't try. Deserialization in Python is a real pickle of a problem if you want to move data fast and not lock the GIL just for the IO. A good explanation as to why these approaches vary so much would also be a good answer.

```
""" Deserialization speed test """
import numpy as np
import pickle
import time
import io


sz = 524288000
sample = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=sz, dtype=np.uint8)  # 500 MB data
serialized_sample = pickle.dumps(sample)
serialized_bytes = sample.tobytes()
serialized_bytesio = io.BytesIO()
np.save(serialized_bytesio, sample, allow_pickle=False)
serialized_bytesio.seek(0)

result = None

print('Deserialize using pickle...')
t0 = time.time()
result = pickle.loads(serialized_sample)
print('Time: {:.10f} sec'.format(time.time() - t0))

print('Deserialize from bytes...')
t0 = time.time()
result = np.ndarray(shape=sz, dtype=np.uint8, buffer=serialized_bytes)
print('Time: {:.10f} sec'.format(time.time() - t0))

print('Deserialize using numpy load from BytesIO...')
t0 = time.time()
result = np.load(serialized_bytesio, allow_pickle=False)
print('Time: {:.10f} sec'.format(time.time() - t0))
```

Results:

```
Deserialize using pickle...
Time: 0.2509949207 sec
Deserialize from bytes...
Time: 0.0204288960 sec
Deserialize using numpy load from BytesIO...
Time: 28.9850852489 sec
```

The second option is the fastest, but notably less elegant because I need to explicitly serialize the shape and dtype information.

Comment: The pun in that quote D:

Comment: `pickle` of a numpy array uses the `np.save` format - a small buffer with shape, etc info followed by a byte copy of the array's data buffer.  I would expect pickle load from file to take about the same time as a np.load`.  I haven't experiemented with the bytestring equivalent(s).

Comment: The `BytesIO` load is slow because `numpy.load` has a [slow path](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/6ee49178517088966e63c2aedf6a8a5779ad5384/numpy/lib/format.py#L739) if the file-like object isn't a real file. It looks like the slow path is a workaround for a GZIP file bug. I wonder if it's still necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found your question useful, I'm looking for best numpy serialization and confirmed that np.load() was best except it was beaten by `pyarrow` in my add on test below. Arrow is now a super popular data serialization framework for distributed compute (E.g. Spark, ...)

```
""" Deserialization speed test """
import numpy as np
import pickle
import time
import io
import pyarrow as pa


sz = 524288000
sample = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=sz, dtype=np.uint8)  # 500 MB data
pa_buf = pa.serialize(sample).to_buffer()

serialized_sample = pickle.dumps(sample)
serialized_bytes = sample.tobytes()
serialized_bytesio = io.BytesIO()
np.save(serialized_bytesio, sample, allow_pickle=False)
serialized_bytesio.seek(0)

result = None

print('Deserialize using pickle...')
t0 = time.time()
result = pickle.loads(serialized_sample)
print('Time: {:.10f} sec'.format(time.time() - t0))

print('Deserialize from bytes...')
t0 = time.time()
result = np.ndarray(shape=sz, dtype=np.uint8, buffer=serialized_bytes)
print('Time: {:.10f} sec'.format(time.time() - t0))

print('Deserialize using numpy load from BytesIO...')
t0 = time.time()
result = np.load(serialized_bytesio, allow_pickle=False)
print('Time: {:.10f} sec'.format(time.time() - t0))

print('Deserialize pyarrow')
t0 = time.time()
restored_data = pa.deserialize(pa_buf)
print('Time: {:.10f} sec'.format(time.time() - t0))
```

Results from i3.2xlarge on Databricks Runtime 8.3ML Python 3.8, Numpy 1.19.2, Pyarrow 1.0.1

```
Deserialize using pickle...
Time: 0.4069395065 sec
Deserialize from bytes...
Time: 0.0281322002 sec
Deserialize using numpy load from BytesIO...
Time: 0.3059172630 sec
Deserialize pyarrow
Time: 0.0031735897 sec
```

Your BytesIO results were about 100x more than mine, which I don't know why.

Comment: note that time.time() is not recommended for performance measurement; at least consider `%timeit`.

Comment: Seems the `pa_buf` is still stored in memory, thus faster?