# What is the opposite function of tobytes()?

Tags: python, numpy, byte

I need a function to turn bytes back to a numpy array. Is there a simple way to do it?

Pickle doesn't work because my data is too long and everything else I tried fails as well... I'm trying to send a frame over a socket from my client to my server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert byte array back to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376786/convert-byte-array-back-to-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `x = np.frombuffer(n, dtype=i.dtype)`