# How to send numpy array over network in Android using chaquo to a Python server using sockets

Tags: python, java, android, sockets, chaquopy

I'm making a face recognition app that uses local camera to capture the face and encodes it into a 128-d numpy array via chaquopy. What I want to make is to send that numpy array over network to a server. The problem is I dont know how to send a numpy array via network or a chaquopy-PyObject efficiently. Please give me advices

I can convert the numpy array into a json file or a string but this time it'll take really long time to execute. Speed is really important so the solution should be the closest to the most efficient way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the array directly to bytes using [`tobytes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html), or at a slightly higher level using [`save`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376786) for further discussion.

Comment: For example, if I were to return that numpy array from python would I still be able to send it over network from java as pyobject? Speed is really important so least amount of conversion would suit me more

Comment: If you want to handle the network connection on the Java side, then the most efficient solution would be to convert the numpy array to bytes in Python, return the `bytes` object to Java, and convert it using [`toJava(byte[].class)`](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/java/com/chaquo/python/PyObject.html#toJava(java.lang.Class)).

Comment: Do you think creating TCP conncetion in java and passing ip adress and port to the python and sending data from there would be more efficient ?

Comment: It probably wouldn't make any difference: passing byte arrays between Python and Java is very efficient. So I recommend you first implement your app in the simplest possible way, and then if it's too slow, do some timing tests to work out exactly where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely try that