# How to insert opencv captured frame by frame by direct to database?

Tags: python, sqlite, opencv

I want to insert captured frame to database. 
please let me know.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
         ret, frame = cap.read()
```

Comment: An image is just a 2D array. An OpenCV image, is a 2D numpy array. Therefore, this question is probably a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18621513/176769

Comment: Okay. But It store like array not image. I want to store as image even using sqlite browser can see the image. It's not off topic.

Comment: `frame` is actually a 2D numpy array, a representation of an image file in RAM memory. sqlite is designed to store data like this. If you want to store the actual image file, you need to look into document-oriented databases like MongoDB or CouchDB.

Comment: My frame is 3D I checked using frame.ndim it's prints 3 dimensional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encode the frame using opencv after insert to the table.

```
image_encode = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tostring()
```